# iOS7 AutoLayout UIButton not receiving touches on entire button

Tags: ios, uibutton, ios7, autolayout

I have a trio of UIButtons in my interface. They have text and a custom background image. I set the size of these buttons explicitly, so as not to have the image distorted. When I have no constraints on the buttons at all, they work fine. When I start trying to pin their size, and pin them to the bottom and to be centered to each other, they stop accepting touches. Well, that's not entirely true: They accept the touches on a small box on the top part of the button. Touches on the rest of the button are ignored. I've printed out the frame and the bounds of the button, and they are not changed from what I set. However, it's still not registering touches on over half the button. The background image is not changed throughout any of this.

Is there anything which might help me figure out why it's not detecting touches?

EDIT: After doing some investigation, it appears I have a very confusing problem. The issue I described only happens on a 4 inch device. When run on a 4 inch device, if I set the main view's background color to "default", there's a large band at the bottom of the screen that's black. It's in this area that hit detection doesn't work. This doesn't show up in IB, as IB simply shows the view as being the correct size for the screen.

This is an old app, one that was originally deployed for iOS 4, I think. I'm not sure if there's something wrong with the UIWindow set up, or what happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, because this is an older app, it had a MainWindow.xib file. And in that MainWindow.xib file, the setting "Full Screen At Launch" was not set. Setting that caused it to work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Walk the subview array, and log every frame. Almost for sure some other view is overlapping the buttons.

So in your viewDidAppear, get the subview array, and print out each view's frame.

This is the only issue I've ever seen relating to "dead" button areas.